# How to copy a data range to the last row on another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a row from another worksheet to the last row of my data tracking sheet.

I get application defined or object defined error.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim A As Integer
    
    Range("A20:AB20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Windows("master tracking sheet.xlsm").Activate
    i = Worksheets("Recieved Results").cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    A = i + 1

    Selection.End(A).Select
    Range(A).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(A).Select` - `A` is not a valid reference. Neither is `Selection.End(A).Select` valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use things like `Select` or `Activate`. As you can declare things as objects in VBA, you can use this to perform most actions in without having to use any of that. Try the code below:

```
Sub CopyFromOneSheetToAnother()

    Dim oCopyFromWS As Worksheet: Set oCopyFromWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")           '<- Change the sheet name to the sheet you want to copy from
    Dim oCopyToWS As Worksheet: Set oCopyToWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")               '<- Change the sheet name to the sheet you want to copy to
    Dim iLR As Long: iLR = oCopyToWS.Cells(oCopyToWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    oCopyFromWS.Range("A20:AB20").Copy oCopyToWS.Range("A" & iLR)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi that great thanks Zac, it works perfectly. if i wanted to then change this from worksheets to workbooks, would i just change it from worksheets to workbooks? thanks again max

Comment: Do you mean for instance if your destination sheet was in another workbook? If so, you just change the following: `Dim oCopyToWS As Worksheet: Set oCopyToWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")` to@ `Dim oCopyToWS As Worksheet: Set oCopyToWS = Workbooks("Name of workbook").Worksheets("Sheet4")`. You have to make sure that the other workbook is open for this to work

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i meant, thank you so much for your help zac

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped